# readfile() script not working after changing server

Tags: php, download, readfile

I had a code that worked, here:

```
if (isset($_GET['file']) && isset($_GET['name']))
{
$file = base64_decode($_REQUEST['file']);

$ch = curl_init($file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) 
{
    // Contains file size in bytes
    $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];
}

header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_REQUEST['name']);
header('Content-Length: ' . $contentLength);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

@readfile($file);

}
```

And than I changed my server to a differenf host providor, and the code stoped working. When I download from chrome it just keeps loading and loading,
but when I download from a download manager like IDM than it gets the correct name and size, but when I press start it makes an error that says something about not supporting resuming or something...

Again, the code worked when I used a different providor.

Comment: This script is a security disaster. You perform absolutely no security checks on the passed-in path and have now opened the door for a malicious user to download **ANY** file on your server without any restrictions. Also, since the script isn't working, don't you think it might be a good idea to **NOT** supress errors? remove the `@` on readfile...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make resumable downloads with readfile() of external link PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337534/make-resumable-downloads-with-readfile-of-external-link-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be errors which are outputted before `readfile()` use `ob_clean();
flush();` to remove any output before `readfile`

Comment: Wouldn't ob_end_flash() do the same thing?